# Lightswitch textboxes are not editable

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

I am building a simple lightswitch application. 
It has two tables, **Cheque** and **Sale**. When i add a new sale, it has the option to select the payment type. And if the cheque option is selected, i need to enter the cheque details for the sale. I have created a modal window to enter the data. but when the window appears, i cant enter new data because the textboxes are disabled.

Simply, i need to enter cheque details regarding to the sale without going to another screen.
Help is much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a 1-Many relationship between the two tables? If you have a 0..1-Many you will have problems if you don't handle it properly.